# How to get FormValueProvider instance in a Custom Model Binder in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the MVC 2 RC. I have a custom model binder that used to iterate over posted form values in MVC 1.0 like this:

```
var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("prefix"));    
foreach (var value in values) { /* do something */ }
```

In version 2, I can't do this anymore. [Apparently there are new implementations of IValueProvider that come with ASP.NET MVC 2.0.](http://mgolchin.net/posts/19/dive-deep-into-mvc-ivalueprovider) I think I need to somehow use FormValueProvider in my custom model binder, but I don't know how to get at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ValueProvider seems to be a read/write property. Have you tried this:

```
var formValueProvider = new FormValueProvider(controllerContext);
bindingContext.ValueProvider = formValueProvider;
```

I discussed this [on another question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958972/asp-net-mvc-2-setting-values-on-ivalueprovider/2133420#2133420) but to be honest I haven't used it myself.

**Edit:** I am not sure if there is a good solution for this scenario, but I guess you might end up accessing controllerContext.HttpContext.Request. I know it doesn't feel right but if your needs are so low level I suspect that's the only way to get to them.

Comment: I guess that's how you can get to the FormValueProvider, but how can iterate form values?